# Item is showing back in the UI after deletion

Tags: react-query

I am new to React Query and I am trying to delete an item and immediatly update the UI.

This is my custom hook for deletion:

```
export const useDeleteItem = (currentBoardId: string) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()
  return useMutation(
    (itemsId: (string | undefined)[]) => {
      return axios.delete(`${BASE_URL}/api/items`, { data: itemsId })
    },

    {
      onMutate: async (itemsId: (string | undefined)[]) => {
       await queryClient.cancelQueries({ queryKey: ['board', currentBoardId] })
        const prevBoard = queryClient.getQueryData<Board>(['board', currentBoardId])
        console.log('file: useQuery.ts:285 -> prevBoard:', prevBoard)
        const filteredBoard = {
          ...prevBoard,
          groups: prevBoard!.groups.map((group) => ({
            ...group,
            items: group.items.filter((item) => !itemsId.includes(item.id)),
          })),
        }
        console.log('file: useQuery.ts:286 -> filteredBoard:', filteredBoard)
        queryClient.setQueryData(['board', currentBoardId], filteredBoard)

        return  filteredBoard 
      },
      onError: (err) => {
        console.log('file: useQuery.ts:308 -> err:', err)
        
      },
      onSuccess: (data, variables, context) => {
        console.log('item deleted!', data, variables, context)
        queryClient.invalidateQueries(['board', context!.id])
      },
    }
  )
}
```

When queryClient.invalidateQueries(['board', context!.id]) is reached on onSuccess, the item is shown back / reappears on the UI, even though it is successfully deleted from the db.

1. on onMutate it is successfully undisplaying the deleted item only when reaching onSuccess it is reappearing.
2. I am sure that the item is deleted from the database.
3. the context is current and shown without the deleted item.

The thing is, I'm not sure how to even start debugging this case.
I have a few more custom hooks that do the same exact logic, for example "useAddItem", and I don't have issues with the other ones.

Any help or guide will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I am sure that the item is deleted from the database.

Well can you check what the network response is (in the network tab of your browser devtools) that is made by `queryClient.invalidateQueries` ? I'm pretty sure that in that network response, you might see that the item is still in the list that is sent from the server.

If that's the case, it just means that your server responded to the `DELETE` request *before* it actually deleted the entry. Could be a missing `await` on the server side (pseudo code):

```
async function deleteItem(item) {
  deleteItemFromDatabase()
  return "item was deleted"
}
```

that just depends on how the server is implemented.